# Can't sync child and parent positions

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, parent-child

I've got a parent and a child object. When I move the child object I want to parent to move to the same position as the child. I'm trying to achieve this with this script on the parent object:

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 childPos = transform.GetChild(0).position;
           
    transform.position = childPos;
           
    transform.GetChild( 0 ).position = childPos;
}
```

So, set the parent's world space position to the child's world space position and then set the child's world space position to what it was before its parent moved. This is the only script affecting the position of either object.

When I then move the child object in the editor it does this weird laggy effect where the object doesn't properly follow the cursor. Here's a gif showing the effect: https://gfycat.com/negativevigorouscicada

I got the following logs which show that somehow the child's world space position is being changed between the end of the frame where it's been set and the start of the next frame:
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAUmv.png)

I was thinking maybe the child's transform gets updated again at some point relative to its parent, but I tried setting the new position in LateUpdate in a script on the child and the problem still happened. Setting the child's local position to 0,0,0 after moving the parent doesn't work either. I tried setting both objects to the position of a separate object and moving that, which didn't cause the lag to happen so it's definitely something to do with the parenting.

Any explanations or ideas as to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Moving the parent object with the child remaining at local (0,0,0) is not an option?

Comment: I think the problem is that you hold gizmo arrow of object that is being moved by script the same time. So basicaly after you move object with script Gizmo arrows recalculate position change and move object in response to that. If you try changing X position in inspector it works smoothly.

Comment: @PawełŁęgowski You're totally right, it was the gizmo. It's really strange that it doesn't happen when setting the position to a separate object though! Thanks for the help. If you reply as an answer I'll mark it as accepted :)